# Minimal plus and minus script for jQuery accordion

Tags: jquery

I am currently learning jQuery and have been working on this particular thing for a couple of days now. What I am trying to do is introduce a plus or minus icon to the right of each panel like: http://www.tutorialsmade.com/demo/accordion_script/ - I can't seem to incorporate it into what I have now. I've tried images as well as actual + and - text characters. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u3a9t9cb/

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function () {
            //Expands or collapses clicked panel
            $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
            //Hides any other expanded panels
            $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
        });

        $('#accordion').find('.sub-accordion-toggle').click(function () {

            //Expand or collapse this panel
            $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

            //Hide the other panels
            $(".sub-accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="accordion">
            <ul>
                <li class="accordion-toggle icon-airlines">Top Level 1</li>
                <ul class="accordion-content">
                    <li class="sub-accordion-toggle">Sub Level 1</li>
                    <li class="sub-accordion-content">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque blandit quam odio, consequat pharetra felis lobortis egestas.</p>
                        <p>Phone: (800) 555-1212</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sub-accordion-toggle">Sub Level 2</li>
                    <li class="sub-accordion-content">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque blandit quam odio, consequat pharetra felis lobortis egestas.</p>
                        <p>Phone: (800) 555-1212</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <li class="accordion-toggle icon-restaurants">Top Level 2</li>
                <ul class="accordion-content">
                    <li class="sub-accordion-toggle">Sub Level 1</li>
                    <li class="sub-accordion-content">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque blandit quam odio, consequat pharetra felis lobortis egestas.</p>
                        <p>Phone:(800) 555-1212</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sub-accordion-toggle">Sub Level 2</li>
                    <li class="sub-accordion-content">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque blandit quam odio, consequat pharetra felis lobortis egestas.</p>
                        <p>Phone:(800) 555-1212</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
/* RESET */
    html, body, address, blockquote, div, form, fieldset, caption, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, hr, ul, li, ol, ul, table, tr, td, th, p, img {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    img, fieldset {
        border:none;
    }
    /* START OF STYLES */
    #accordion {
        position:relative;
        margin:0 auto;
        width:522px;
        font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    }
    .accordion-toggle {
        background-color:#0168b3;
        font-weight:normal;
        font-size:20px;
        color:#fff;
        line-height:100%;
        padding:16px 0 16px 48px;
    }
    .icon-airlines {
        background: url('../images/icon-ai.png') 8px 10px no-repeat;
        background-color:#0168b3;
    }
    .icon-restaurants {
        background: url('../images/icon-r.png') 8px 10px no-repeat;
        background-color:#0168b3;
    }
    .icon-shopping {
        background: url('../images/icon-s.png') 8px 10px no-repeat;
        background-color:#0168b3;
    }
    .icon-amenities {
        background: url('../images/icon-am.png') 8px 10px no-repeat;
        background-color:#0168b3;
    }
    .accordion-toggle:hover {
        background-color:#045c8f;
    }
    .status-plus {
        float:right;
        height:52px;
        width:52px;
        padding:0;
        content:"+";
        text-align:right;
        clear:both;
        display:none;
    }
    .status-minus {
        float:right;
        content:"-";
        text-align:right;
        clear:both;
    }
    .accordion-toggle {
        cursor: pointer;
        margin:0 0 1px 0;
    }
    .accordion-content {
        display: none;
    }
    .accordion-content.default {
        display: block;
    }
    .accordion-content {
        background:#02324d;
    }
    .sub-accordion-toggle {
        cursor: pointer;
        color:#fff;
        font-size:18px;
        font-weight:normal;
        line-height:100%;
        padding:10px 0 10px 20px;
    }
    .sub-accordion-toggle:hover {
        background:#02283e;
    }
    .sub-accordion-content {
        display: none;
    }
    .sub-accordion-content {
        background:#fff;
    }
    .sub-accordion-content p {
        color:#222222;
        font-size:16px;
        font-weight:normal;
        line-height:21px;
        padding:6px 12px;
    }
    .accordion-toggle, .sub-accordion-toggle, .sub-accordion-content {
        list-style-type:none;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use the (jquery ui accordion)[http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#custom-icons]? It has events, icons,etc all wrapped up for you? If not add a span to your li's `<li class="accordion-toggle icon-airlines"><span>+</span> Top Level 1</li>`

Comment: I **[Forked](http://jsfiddle.net/gtd7pLg6/1/)** your fiddle. Anytime I've done this I've added an identifier class such as `plus` or `minus` to the clicked class to determine the state of the click which we can use to toggle the icons.
There's more logic to determine if its sibling has the `+` or `-` that I'm working on.

Comment: I've updated the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtd7pLg6/3/)** to reflect the `+` and `-` changes when clicking on an alternate accordion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a class to your accordions to reflect their collapsed state. Based on the toggled class the javascript removes the `+` or `-` on the `clicked` object and toggles the icon for the sibling.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtd7pLg6/3/)

```js
//Expands or collapses clicked panel
if ($(this).hasClass('plus')) {
  // if this is closed
  if ($(this).siblings('li').hasClass('minus')) {
    $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('minus').addClass('plus');
  }
  $(this).removeClass('plus').addClass('minus').next().slideToggle('fast');
} else {
  if ($(this).siblings('li').hasClass('plus')) {
    $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('minus').addClass('plus');
  }
  $(this).removeClass('minus').addClass('plus').next().slideToggle('fast');
}
```

```css
.accordion-toggle.plus:before {
    content: "+ ";
}
.accordion-toggle.minus:before {
    content: "- ";
}
```

Comment: You're very welcome. Don't hesitate to ask any more questions.